# How to add meta information to captured image in ANDROID STUDIO

Tags: android, image, image-processing

I'm a newbie in Android . Here's my problem:

I want to add some information like:
-Name
-Age
-User's Comment

into an image that I just captured, and all of those information can be saved along with the image captured, in the internal storage. But I am seriously blank and don't know how to do that. I basically have done the image capturing part and now stuck on how to add some information/metadata.

I've read some cases that use ExifInterface but still can't find a way.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

easy and dirty way just use sharepref to keep
meta data and keep part of the img

e.g.

```
-Name : bla
-Age  : 12
-User's Comment : blabla
-Img  : path/img_name.jpg
```

Another more professional way is use db/room to keep meta data with same idea of the above